# What's the best way to get photos from Lightroom 3 to Flickr?

Tags: software, lightroom-3, flickr

As someone who publishes a lot of photos on Flickr, I'd like to know the best way to export my photos.  I see that Lightroom 3 has a built-in publishing tool... is that the best option or are there better ways such as third-party plugins?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jeffrey's Lightroom Exporter seems to be the most popular...
http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies

Comment: I second this.  An excellent plugin.  In fact, his plugins for lightroom, picassa, and facebook are all top notch.

Comment: Data Plot is my favorite.

Answer (score 3):

I usually just export to a file, then upload the files to Flickr.  I'm not using any of the tagging or library features of Lightroom though; I'm just using it to post-process so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

I've had no problems at all using the built in Flickr plug in.

The only minor issue is that it doesn't seem to show you photos you've previously uploaded before you started using the Lightroom Flickr export.