# Updating pictures on Flickr with Lightroom which were originally not added with Lightroom

Tags: lightroom, software, flickr

A while back, before I purchased LR3, I uploaded a few hundred photos to Flickr. Since, I received comments and fave's on several of them. However, I want to update them. Many need a little cropping done, others need to be adjusted, and so on. Now that I have LR3, I can manage my pictures on Flickr quite well, but how to I sync it with these pictures that were not originally added in LR.

I should mention that I have these photos in Lightroom, they are just not synced up with those on Flickr.

I know this is a little bit outside the normal questions on this site, but I think it is still within the bounds.

Comment: You may want to check this question too - http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2384/how-to-import-photos-and-metadata-from-flickr-to-lightroom

Comment: @Andre Thanks for the link, I had forgotten about that question(but have apparently read and voted up answers in it.)

Comment: This is exactly the dilemma I faced a few months back. I needed to sort out quite a few things with my (relatively small) image library, though, so embarked on a mass project to start again when my Flickr account needed renewing. Took ages. Bah!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can. The association between the Flickr Publish service in LR3 and the Flickr photo itself is maintained in Lightroom's Catalog. It doesn't seem to be exposed in the interface. You would need to hack in the LR3's SQLite database to change this bit of info, or create a plugin.

But wait. One way to associate your Flickr photos back to your pictures in LR is to use Jeffrey Friedl's [“Export to Flickr” Lightroom Plugin](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/flickr). I don't use that plugin anymore since I switched to LR3, but it has a little known feature that could help you. Select the photos you want to associate in LR, then in the "File -> Plugin Extras -> Flickr Extras" submenu select "Associate Images". The plugin will try to find the corresponding photos on your Flickr by matching capture time. The association (i.e. the Flickr photo URL) will be displayed in the plugin metadata in the right panel.

From there, I *think* you can crop your photos in LR and use the plugin to update them on Flickr. You won't be able to use LR's Flickr Publish service for these though, because it is unaware of the plugin's metadata that stores the association. Give it a shot?

Comment: hmm sad. I will look into that Plugin. That might have to work. :/

Comment: That's best answer I can give, but keep us posted, I would be interested in associating my old Flickr photos too. Thx.

Comment: just a partial update, I haven't yet played with this. I will in the next week or so, and then update this thread. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Jeffrey Friedl's "Export to Flickr" plugin does all the same things as the Lightroom Flickr publisher (which is very basic) but adds synching of photos already in Flickr (as described in the answer above).  So it's not a compromise - its a step forward.

The [manual is here](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/flickr/publish) - it's a bit daunting but read it a few times.